# Any way to install a 'metro' app without a developer's licence?

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

If I develop an app for the (formerly) metro UI, is there any way (no matter how hacky or unpleasant) to install my app on my computer without having a developer's license?

Comment: If you are developing the app, then surely you can already run it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can *run* it, but I want it to actually be installed, with a tile on the start screen.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 official ways to sideload apps into Windows 8:

- Obtain a developer licence for the machine, however these do expire and without a store account the time until expiry is very short. Sideloaded apps will not work once the licence has expired until it is renewed.
- Use Windows 8 Enterprise and set a group policy to enable it, but the app must still be signed by a certificate trusted by the client PC
- Use Windows 8 Professional and activate it with a special sideloading product key (though these will only be available via Volume Licencing in bundles)

The TechNet article [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852635.aspx) gives full details.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the PowerShell Script (what you want to do) to install your app on another machine, it will automatically show a [dialog to request a developer license](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974578.aspx#getting_a_developer_license_at_a_command_prompt). You don't need Visual Studio for that. 
But after the developer license is out of date, your application will not start. Maybe an uninstall and reinstall will help.

You would only use this for testing purposes. Otherwise you should really get a Windows Store Account to deploy your application.

Maybe [sideloading](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852635.aspx) would be an option for you, but I didn't dive into this, so I can't provide more information here. 
Short blog from MS about [sideloading](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uk_faculty_connection/archive/2012/04/03/installing-enterprise-metro-apps-without-using-microsoft-store.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You know,I did the same thing in my copy of Windows 8.1 Enterprise with the help of a small trick.First of all,I created a Package of my windows Metro app in Visual Studio 2013,then installed the certificate as trusted on my local Machine as well as Current user,and made a "few" changes in the powershell script generated my Visual studio.That did the job very well and no problems are being faced by me yet.

Answer (score -2):

You can install the Windows 8 app without developer license. Just right click the Project and Select store->Create App Packages and follow on screen instructions. 
It will generate the required package files along with the certificate. Now go to the folder and edit the Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 powershell script file. Replace the line

```
`$NeedDeveloperLicense = CheckIfNeedDeveloperLicense`
```

with

```
$NeedDeveloperLicense = $false
```

Now, if you run the powershell script you can install the Windows Store Application without any issues.

Comment: This bypasses the check in the Install script but the deployment will still fail  with the error: Deployment of package  %packagename% failed because no
valid license or sideloading policy could be applied. A developer license
(http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=233074) or enterprise sideloading
configuration (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=231020) may be required.